# JavaScript animating short strokes and long strokes

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

Hi guys i am trying to make a clock for my website using javascrit and raphael . Its working perfectly and i am just trying to make it look nicer. At the moment i have 12 dashs appearing for the number e.g 12 , 1 , 2 , 3 etc for the time. However i want 4 extra dashes between the big dashes i have got.

Example : 
[image]

However i cant get the little dashs to appear. I tried to do it the same way as my big dashes but no luck unfortunately. Any help on this matter would be great.

This is what i have tried :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly just transform the same path around the center of the clock in 6 deg chunks, in some ways that feels more intuitive, but it depends what you prefer to work with...so you could do something like the following, it just depends if you mind transforms being on the elements, you may prefer to avoid that.

This will draw both sets of lines.

```
for(i=0;i<60;i++){
  if( i % 5 != 0 ) {
    paper.path('M40,40L45,45').transform('r'+(i*360/60+45)+',100,100')
  } else {
    paper.path('M40,40L55,55').transform('r'+(i*360/12+45)+',100,100');
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEaFx/12/)

Comment: Ah this is fantatic , i will give it a go with this example and see what i can do, thanks for the help xx

Comment: i do have 1 more question, if i wanted to change the colours of the big dashs and little one is there a way to do this? as none of them have a variable

Comment: Sure, just set the attribute you want with .attr(), see example at http://jsfiddle.net/WEaFx/14/

Comment: Ur fantastic help as always,